# efficient for querying large plists?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

I am planning to do search on large plists. say around 900 plists with data ranging from 120 to 250kb. which one is efficient for searching large plist ?? core data or sqlite ?

Comment: None of the mentioned technologies does actually read plist files. 
Given the size of data you should consider importing your data into a sqlite database if it has a simple datastructure.

Comment: can we have data inserted in core data file ?

Comment: you can write an importer using the core data framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: don't do that.

Instead, import all of this data into Core Data and then do everything else within Core Data.  plist files are not good for this at all.  If you are receiving the data from a server in plist format then great, import it into Core Data.

If you have control of the output of the server then I **highly** recommend using JSON instead.  You can set up the data structures to make your import into Core Data very easy to manage, far easier than dealing with plists.